# Swift play alarm sound

Tags: ios, swift, audio, alarm, uialertcontroller

I have an alert that pops up when the user runs out of time. Right now it just vibrates but I also want it to play an alarm sound. Is there a way to play whatever the user has set as the system default alarm sound is? Also, is it possible to have the alarm keep going until the user clicks the dismiss button?

Here is my code so far:

```
func dismissAlert(alert:UIAlertAction!)
        {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

let outOfTimeAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Out Of Time", message: "Better luck next time", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

let cancelAlert: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Cancel, handler: dismissAlert)

outOfTimeAlert.addAction(cancelAlert)

presentViewController(outOfTimeAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
```

Thanks for the help!